# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on a dispatch_get_main_queue()

Tags: ios, objective-c, init, dispatch-async, alloc

I have this code, and some times the variable dConfiguration is Nil and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and most of the time the variable said 0 key/value pairs, and the error is almost imposible to reproduce, I just click my button and most of the time work but in rare occasions it fails.

```
serviceData = data;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [loading removeFromSuperview];
    _tvTable.hidden = NO;
    dConfiguration =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:serviceData options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    if (![[dConfiguration objectForKey:@"NumberOfLines"] isEqual: [NSNull null]]) {
        _NumberOfLines = [[dConfiguration objectForKey:@"NumberOfLines"] integerValue];
    } else {
        _NumberOfLines = 1;
    }
    if(badget!=nil){
        dBadgets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:badget options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    }
    dValue = [dConfiguration objectForKey:sButtonType];
    RowCount = (int)dValue.count;
    [_tvTable numberOfRowsInSection:RowCount];
    [self loadTable];
});
```

This variable is declared as global in the implementation:

```
@implementation vcTableViewEventsManagerEvents {
    NSDictionary *dConfiguration;
}
```

I have never implemented the alloc init code:

```
dConfiguration = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

Does this can be the problem? if I always init the variable this error will not occur? It is a good practice to always do the initialisation? Where can I see a more detailed information of the EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Thanks to all your help.

**UPDATE 1**

I have tried the to see the error as all commented and maybe I'm doing something wrong because the error variable is nil this are the screen shoots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

In this particular time the variable dConfiguration said 0 key/value pairs because I added the alloc init.

I have tried with double click and changing from the tabbar items as fast as I can and sometimes work and some times it does not.

**UPDATE 2**

As you asked this is the BT of the error:

> thread #1: tid = 0x7bfdfd, 0x2537dd52 Foundation`newJSONString + 98,
>   queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,
>   address=0x3fe64a2)
>       frame #0: 0x2537dd52 Foundation`newJSONString + 98
>       frame #1: 0x2537d300 Foundation`newJSONValue + 1976
>       frame #2: 0x2537cf04 Foundation`newJSONValue + 956
>       frame #3: 0x2537d380 Foundation`newJSONValue + 2104
>       frame #4: 0x2537ca80 Foundation`-[_NSJSONReader parseUTF8JSONData:skipBytes:options:] + 176
>       frame #5: 0x2537c88e Foundation`-[_NSJSONReader parseData:options:] + 238
>       frame #6: 0x2537c718 Foundation`+[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 156
>       frame #7: 0x00121b24 guestperience`__43-[vcTableViewEventsManagerEvents
>   checkJson]_block_invoke_2(.block_descriptor=0x17040f40) + 244 at
>   vcTableViewEventsManagerEvents.m:298
>       frame #8: 0x00495b7e libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
>       frame #9: 0x00495b6a libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 22
>       frame #10: 0x0049a654 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1680
>       frame #11: 0x24b81bdc CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
>       frame #12: 0x24b800d6 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1574
>       frame #13: 0x24acf2e8 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
>       frame #14: 0x24acf0d4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
>       frame #15: 0x260bfac8 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 160
>       frame #16: 0x291940b8 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 144
>       frame #17: 0x001cb6f0 guestperience`main(argc=1, argv=0x00473b5c) + 106 at main.m:16
>       frame #18: 0x24777872 libdyld.dylib`start + 2

**UPDATE 3**

I have executed this command in the console to see the JSON and to me looks correct:

```
(lldb) po (NSString *)[[NSString alloc] initWithData:serviceData encoding:4]

{
    "BackgroundImage": null,
    "ButtonGallery": null,
    "Buttons": null,
    "ButtonsEvents": [{
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "04 JUN 2016 - Horario: 11.00 - 18.00",
        "Id": 23,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_15f37703-f0a0-4f10-be70-76e0118fa9f9_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_15f37703-f0a0-4f10-be70-76e0118fa9f9_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "134",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "134es",
        "Label": "Brazil Pool Party",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Brazil Pool Party",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "23 JUN 2016 - Horario: 20:00 - 01:00",
        "Id": 29,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_5af125bb-1bdf-4fcf-9306-3b565cdbb928_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_5af125bb-1bdf-4fcf-9306-3b565cdbb928_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "140",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "140es",
        "Label": "Noche de San Juan",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche de San Juan",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "02 JUL 2016 - Horario: 21:00 - 1:00",
        "Id": 30,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_7227de52-8d27-4a65-bdf7-dea08e37b968_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_7227de52-8d27-4a65-bdf7-dea08e37b968_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "141",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "141es",
        "Label": "Noche Amàre",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche Amàre",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "09 JUL 2016 - Horario: 22:00 - 00:00",
        "Id": 28,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_4ad05ca3-c345-4a6f-aeb9-972610056b86_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_4ad05ca3-c345-4a6f-aeb9-972610056b86_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "139",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "139es",
        "Label": "Noche Flamenca Beach",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche Flamenca Beach",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "20 JUL 2016 - Horario: 19:00 - 22:00",
        "Id": 27,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_161bab39-5ac6-43a0-84c4-5c0fa764b5b0_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_161bab39-5ac6-43a0-84c4-5c0fa764b5b0_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "138",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "138es",
        "Label": "Noche de luna llena",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche de luna llena",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "23 JUL 2016 - Horario: 21:00 - 00:00",
        "Id": 26,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_c657d56d-5f24-4f28-8d0c-66afb2fae1ad_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_c657d56d-5f24-4f28-8d0c-66afb2fae1ad_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "137",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "137es",
        "Label": "Noche cubana",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche cubana",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "06 AGO 2016 - Horario: 22:00 - 00:00",
        "Id": 31,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_98032ab6-b689-42d6-b19b-6b82705478a3_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_98032ab6-b689-42d6-b19b-6b82705478a3_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "142",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "142es",
        "Label": "Noche Flamenca Beach",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche Flamenca Beach",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "13 AGO 2016 - Horario: 21:00 - 00:00",
        "Id": 32,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_447f28d9-ed38-4482-868e-74743cbb5a89_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_447f28d9-ed38-4482-868e-74743cbb5a89_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "143",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "143es",
        "Label": "Noche cubana",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Noche cubana",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "10 SEP 2016 - Horario: 11:00 - 18:00",
        "Id": 33,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_a7328a94-d64d-4fd4-b0a1-a2c126c8c92c_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_a7328a94-d64d-4fd4-b0a1-a2c126c8c92c_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "144",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "144es",
        "Label": "Pool Party",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Pool Party",
        "ViewController": 21
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "17 SEP 2016 - Horario: 12:00 - 18:00",
        "Id": 25,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_9f8af8e5-56d7-433f-9661-9403196faad8_x320.jpg",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_9f8af8e5-56d7-433f-9661-9403196faad8_x320.jpg",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "136",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "136es",
        "Label": "Oktoberfest",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Oktoberfest",
        "ViewController": 21
    }],
    "ButtonsPromotions": [{
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 18,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_ba95942c-1ece-4332-9f95-eb3f95738f41_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_ba95942c-1ece-4332-9f95-eb3f95738f41_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "126",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "126es",
        "Label": "Desayuna con Nosotros",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Desayuna con Nosotros",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 19,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_3b9f1e44-5f33-4eb9-987b-5e50dcaed2a7_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_3b9f1e44-5f33-4eb9-987b-5e50dcaed2a7_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "127",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "127es",
        "Label": "Disfruta de Nuestra Cena Buffet",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Disfruta de Nuestra Cena Buffet",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 20,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_f0ec90c9-3383-48f7-b5cf-28a236aee9e9_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_f0ec90c9-3383-48f7-b5cf-28a236aee9e9_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "128",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "128es",
        "Label": "Alquiler de Bicicletas Vintage",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Alquiler de Bicicletas Vintage",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 21,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_f72a03bf-ddd2-486e-a289-cb3e82bd08db_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_f72a03bf-ddd2-486e-a289-cb3e82bd08db_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "129",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "129es",
        "Label": "Parking",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Parking",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 22,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_3dd87e35-2ae3-4ef2-a70a-f1b44e41d27a_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_3dd87e35-2ae3-4ef2-a70a-f1b44e41d27a_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "130",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "130es",
        "Label": "Ofertas de Grab & Go",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Ofertas de Grab & Go",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 13,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_b8187a48-1b03-4b29-a403-f03af8433c4f_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_b8187a48-1b03-4b29-a403-f03af8433c4f_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "92",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "92es",
        "Label": "Habitación \"The One\"",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Habitación \"The One\"",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 14,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_fc20ec9b-2107-4828-9796-d5234dbe80fd_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_fc20ec9b-2107-4828-9796-d5234dbe80fd_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "98",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "98es",
        "Label": "Disfruta de una Salida de Habitación más Tarde",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Disfruta de una Salida de Habitación más Tarde",
        "ViewController": 20
    }, {
        "BadgeCount": 0,
        "ClientId": 0,
        "Frequency": "",
        "Id": 15,
        "Image": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_be514668-27d0-4ee8-995e-0f8f89936c9b_x320.png",
        "ImageHeighlighted": null,
        "ImageIconTitle": "",
        "ImageRetina": "http:\/\/ServerCloud.CloudApp.net\/DesktopServerCloud\/ClientData\/4\/Images\/GVT_be514668-27d0-4ee8-995e-0f8f89936c9b_x320.png",
        "ImageRetinaHeighlighted": null,
        "Item": "103",
        "ItemType": null,
        "JsonConfigFile": "103es",
        "Label": "Habitación categoría superior",
        "LongTitle": null,
        "Selector": "btnAction:",
        "SubLabel": null,
        "Title": "Habitación categoría superior",
        "ViewController": 20
    }],
    "ButtonsTabList": null,
    "DatePeriod": null,
    "Details": null,
    "Disclaimer": null,
    "MessageList": null,
    "NoBooking": null,
    "NumberOfLines": 2,
    "Pins": null,
    "Selector": null,
    "ServiceType": null,
    "TabList": null,
    "Texts": null,
    "Titles": null,
    "Url": null,
    "UserCode": null
}
```

Comment: You don't need the alloc/init since you do [NSJSONSerialization stuff] and assign the return value to it. But when it occurs, is `serviceData` nil? Also, could you put a `NSError` parameter in the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`? If you click twice quickly on the button, does it occurs?

Comment: Try passing an error variable at the line

Comment: As an aside: anyone who posts to SO about a crash or error, and has a method call where `nil` is being passed to the `NSError **` parameter, should have their SO posting privileges immediately removed.  That's the absolute basic level of debugging.  (As it happens, it wouldn't help with this crash, but still, the effort should be expended before coming to SO.)

Comment: @Larme serviceData is not nil and it have the correct JSON data, and the error happens when I change sections in my tabbar quickly, I will try to pass the error variable and post the results

Comment: @AvinashSharma  I will try to pass the error variable and post the results

Comment: You are doing `async` stuff. Do you put `serviceData = nil` somewhere? For instance, if you put it to nil, doing quickly two calls of this code may cause the issue.

Comment: I guess serviceData variable becomes nil in bad cases.  Larme's suggestion is correct.

Comment: Can we have a proper stacktrace please.  Also why call `[_tvTable numberOfRowsInSection:RowCount];`?

Comment: @Larme I have checked and the I never set that variable to nil, in fact I have just removed it

Comment: @trojanfoe how can I get the stack trace?

Comment: If it crashes in Xcode then you can type `bt` in the console.  If it crashes in the wild then Apple will collect the crash report.  There is not enough information to answer your question at the moment.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have added the BT, this time it took a while to reproduce the error like 10 minutes

Comment: @Larme I have added more information thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you modify a variable inside a block, you must use the `__block` specifier

```
__block NSDictionary *dConfiguration;


__block NSData *serviceData = data;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  //...
});
```

Comment: Can I use a __block specifier in a global variable? or should I have to make a copy and the use that one?

Comment: Thanks for the help but the __block specifier did not work

Comment: At the end I have simplified the code, but until and it was more difficult to reproduce but it was still happening, so I added the __block specifier and since yesterday I have not been able to reproduce the error so I'm going to set this answer as the correct.

Comment: Hi @MarcoAntonioUzcateguiPescoz sorry for the answer delay. I'm glad that my answer led you to the solution. Have a great day